# Show Firebase RealTime Database data in a widget in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

using firebase realtime database with flutter, saving user details in realtime database & will be displayed in their profile page. I am able to store and get data from database, but the data does not reflect on the screen, I am trying to show the data as an initial value in the text field. How can I show data on profile page when user clicks on the profile?

```
  getUserDetails() async {
    final userProfileDetails = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("userDetails")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     setState(() {
       email = snapshot.value['email'];
       city = snapshot.value['city'];
       state = snapshot.value['state'];
     });
    });
    return data;
  }
```

widget tree -
Scaffold > Column > TextFormFields

```
                 TextFormField(
                    initialValue: email,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      petName = value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.email,
                          color: grey700,
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email'),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see live-changes from the db you meed to make use of the provider & stream principles of flutter.

In short: you are creating a stream which delivers the desired data (a stream is listening to a specific collection/document). So if some data of the stream is changed you get a notification. The notification ends up in the provider you have to wrap a widget with. Every time the stream delivers new data your wrapped widget and everything below gets rebuild.